# Stripe Card On File function and flow

Tags: stripe-payments

I am using Stripe and want to implement a Card On File functionality. So it would be something like.

1. User enters credit card on UI using Stripe Elements
2. Card is saved and then we charge them every month/week etc

I have been using PaymentIntent to create charges, but I can't reuse them, so what is the proper flow?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Payment Intents, you can pass the [parameter](https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents/create#create_payment_intent-setup_future_usage) `setup_future_usage: 'off_session'`, which will make sure the Payment Method can be charged in the future without your Customer being in the payment flow. From there, you just create another Payment Intent in the future.

The above workflow is documented here: https://stripe.com/docs/payments/save-during-payment

Alternatively, you can use Setup Intents to setup a Payment Method for future usage. The workflow is largely the same, except you wouldn't charge the customer right away. As with before, you would create a Payment Intent after the card is setup to charge the customer.

This workflow is documented here: https://stripe.com/docs/payments/save-and-reuse?platform=web&ui=elements

Once your customer has completed one of the above flows, you can move over to creating Subscriptions for them per: https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/build-subscriptions

Comment: Also with the subscriptions, are you saying once I have a PaymentIntent, for example from a previous payment, I could convert it to a subscription? I can't see how to do that.